# How to save web pages completely

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to save web pages for offline reading. Currently I save it using `firefox`. For bulk saving I want to automate the process using a script (or what about a web site copier like `webhttrack`?). From terminal I can save the .html file of the URL (using `wget URL`) but can't view the page as no image, .js, etc.

Sometimes I want to save numbered pages, ie. https://askubuntu.com/posts/1, https://askubuntu.com/posts/2, https://askubuntu.com/posts/3, https://askubuntu.com/posts/4 ..  (like mirroring) in one shot.

How can I bulk save web pages with all necessary file to view it properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a great little firefox addon called `ScrapBook` that'll do what you want. Just install it by clicking the `Add to Firefox` button on the addon's website over at Mozilla.

Here's the [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/scrapbook/)

Comment: Can I change the file name of saved page to the tile of web page from YY:MM:DD ?

Comment: What abt bulk saving ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use wget, but read the manual for the actual options you need.

Pay special attention to options like

> ‘-p’
>   ‘--page-requisites’
>   This option causes Wget to download all the
>   files that are necessary to properly display a given html page. This
>   includes such things as inlined images, sounds, and referenced
>   stylesheets.

or even

> ‘-m’
>   ‘--mirror’
>   Turn on options suitable for mirroring. This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps ftp directory listings. It is currently > equivalent to ‘-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing’.

Hell, check out, if you feel like it,

> ‘-k’
>   ‘--convert-links’
>   After the download is complete, convert the
>   links in the document to make them suitable for local viewing. This
>   affects not only the visible hyperlinks, but any part of the document
>   that links to external content, such as embedded images, links to
>   style sheets, hyperlinks to non-html content, etc.

resulting in something like:

```
wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P ./LOCAL_PATH WWW.WEBSITE.TLD/PATH
```

Comment: Not helping, am I? Well, suit yourself then. Be sure to take a look at the documentation [(I know right? reading)](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html)  and search for "external". Play around with the `-r` and `-l` options. **And please mention what you tried in your question instead of in snarky comments.**